# How to post data to express server from front end which don't use forms?

Tags: html, forms, express, server-side-rendering, fetch-api

My front end doesn't use forms. Every input tags are under different "dd" tags and there finally an anchor tag to send .

```html
<dl class="row">
  <dt class="col-sm-3">Project Title</dt>
  <dd class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="mb-3 ">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title">
    </div>
  </dd>

  <dt class="col-sm-3">Project Description</dt>
  <dd class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="mb-3 ">
      <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
  </dd>

  <dt class="col-sm-3">TechStack</dt>
  <dd class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="mb-3 ">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="techStack">
    </div>
  </dd>

  <dt class="col-sm-3 text-truncate">Tags</dt>
  <dd class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="row g-3 align-items-center">
      <div class="col-6">
        <input type="text" id="tag" class="form-control" aria-describedby="tagHelpInline">
      </div>
      <div class="col-auto">
        <span id="tagHelpInline" class="form-text">
                    Give "," seperated tags.
                  </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </dd>

  </dd>
</dl>

<div class="card shadow-sm bg-body rounded">
  <div class="card-header">
    Upload Your Project
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
    <p class="card-text">
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="inputGroupFile02">
      </div>
    </p>
    <a href="#" class="btn uploadBtn">Upload</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

When I use form to post data , I give method and action attrs and things are sorted as data goes in req.body to the server .

But in this case how data can be sent ? One thing that I can think of is Fetch Api or Axios , but these both won't allow server side rendering as far as I know.

So is there any other way to post data to server and do SSR ?

Thanks for any help !

Comment: It really depends upon what outcome you're trying to get in the browser.   When using a form post the browser will automatically render whatever HTML the form post returns as a response.  With an Ajax call (with `fetch()` or `axios()`, the browser does not render anything.  The response from the Ajax call comes back to your  Javascript and your Javascript has to then decide what to do with it.  Your client-side Javascript can take the response, insert it into the current page, replace the contents of the current page with new HTML or whatever else you can do from Javascript.

Comment: You can also have the server respond to your Ajax with a redirect URL and your Javascript could then redirect to a new URL (by setting `window.location` to a new URL), the browser would request the new URL and  your server would render the new page and the browser would display it.

Comment: FYI there's no reason I can see that your exact same presentation couldn't use forms and let the browser submit the data and render the result automaticallyl unless there's some Javascript that has to be involved in collecting the appropriate data.

Comment: Sure , this whole thing can use forms without any problem , it was mainly for knowledge purpose .
As you mentioned about window.location , what will be in req object sent via this url ?

Comment: I don't understand what "what will be in req object sent via this url" means?  If you just want to inform the client about a new location, you can send a 302 response status with the location header containing the new URL.  The browser will NOT automatically act on that if it was from an ajax call (since Ajax results just go back to your Javascript) so your ajax Javascript code has to see the 302 status on the response, fetch the `location` header from it and set `window.location` to that URL.

Comment: Lets say , after an ajax call , I get something back from server to the ajax result , after this , if I set windows.location to some url which is on my server itself , so it is going to hit some api in my server , so that api will recieve a request object , I am asking about that what will be in that req object ?

Comment: If you set `windows.location` to a URL on your server, then the browser will do a GET request to that host and `req.path` will be the path of the URL that was requested.